# understanding std::bad_alloc in C++ class

Tags: c++, class, bad-alloc

I am trying to understand the C++ classes by making a class for matrice operations. I have discovered an dumps error! I am having received the following literature from the compiler:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std:bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is my programming:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(double &a, double &b)
{
    double temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

class matric
{
public:
    int row;
    double *pData = new double[row *row];
    void input();
    void output();

    int InverseMatrix(matric m1);

    int det(matric m1);

    void multiply(matric m1, matric m2);

};
void matric::input()
{
    int i, j;
    cout << "enter the size of matrix:";
    cin >> row;
    cout << "enter the matrix:" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < row; j++)
        {
            cin >> pData[i * row + j];
        }
    }
}
void matric::output()
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < row; j++)
        {
            cout << pData[i * row + j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void matric::multiply(matric m1, matric m2)
{
    int j1 = 0, k1 = 0, j2 = 0, k2 = 0;

    for (j1 = 0; j1 < row; j1++)
    {
        for (k2 = 0; k2 < row; k2++)
        {
            *(pData + j1 * row + k2) = 0;
            for (k1 = 0; k1 < row; k1++)
            {
                *(pData + j1 * row + k2) += *(m1.pData + j1 * row + k1) * (*(m2.pData + j2 * row + k2));
                j2++;
            }
            j2 = 0;
        }
    }


}


int matric::InverseMatrix(matric m1)
{
    double *m = new double[row * row];
    double *ptemp, *pt = m;

    int i, j;

    ptemp = pData;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < row; j++)
        {
            *pt = *ptemp;
            ptemp++;
            pt++;
        }
    }

    int k;

    int *is = new int[row], *js = new int[row];

    for (k = 0; k < row; k++)
    {
        double max = 0;
        for (i = k; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (j = k; j < row; j++)
            {
                if (fabs(*(m + i * row + j)) > max)
                {
                    max = *(m + i * row + j);
                    is[k] = i;
                    js[k] = j;
                }
            }
        }

        if (0 == max)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        if (is[k] != k)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                swap(*(m + k * row + i), *(m + is[k]*row + i));
            }
        }

        if (js[k] != k)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                swap(*(m + i * row + k), *(m + i * row + js[k]));
            }
        }

        *(m + k * row + k) = 1 / (*(m + k * row + k));

        for (j = 0; j < row; j++)
        {
            if (j != k)
            {
                *(m + k * row + j) *= *((m + k * row + k));
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            if (i != k)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < row; j++)
                {
                    if (j != k)
                    {
                        *(m + i * row + j) -= *(m + i * row + k) **(m + k * row + j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            if (i != k)
            {
                *(m + i * row + k) *= -(*(m + k * row + k));
            }
        }
    }

    int r;
    for (r = row - 1; r >= 0; r--)
    {
        if (js[r] != r)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < row; j++)
            {
                swap(*(m + r * row + j), *(m + js[r]*row + j));
            }
        }
        if (is[r] != r)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                swap(*(m + i * row + r), *(m + i * row + is[r]));
            }
        }
    }

    ptemp = pData;
    pt = m;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < row; j++)
        {
            *ptemp = *pt;
            ptemp++;
            pt++;
        }
    }
    delete []is;
    delete []js;
    delete []m;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    matric m1;
    m1.input();
    m1.output();

    matric m2;
    m2.input();
    m2.output();
    cout << "creating m3" << endl;
    matric m3;
    m3.input();
    m3.multiply(m1, m2);
    m3.output();

    matric m4;
    m4.InverseMatrix(m1);
    m4.output();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm fascinated that this compiles without warning, even when I use `-Wall -pedantic`.  There's a blatant error in the initializer for `pData`.

Comment: ianacp: Did you try stepping through with a debugger to see where the error occurs?  What compiler are you using?

Comment: Where is the destructor for your memory? Why not use `std::swap`?

Comment: Think about this: What is the value of `row` when `new double[row *row]` is used to initialize your `pData` member? What do you *want* it to do? When do you know the actual row count so you can `new` a memory block of the correct size? I am not saying that's the only error, but it looks suspicious.

Comment: There is no way anyone can sift through your huge code dump and isolate your problem. That is your job before you post the question.

Comment: I am verry sorry remyabel and did not meant disrespect. The error is at creation of new metric called m3. There is m1 created, there is m2 created and then there is m3 created and it errors. Searches say that it is because the computer has no more volatile memory but I think this is rubbish.

Comment: For starters, give the Matrix class a reasonable constructor and destructor, and either ban copy and assignment, or implement them correctly.  The initializer on the data member is fine for very simple things, but isn't appropriate here.

Comment: @iancp Look at Oguk's comment. `row` is probably a garbage value resulting in an extraordinarily large allocation.

Comment: Neil Kirk thank you. I do not know about std::swap. I will use it.

Comment: @ianacp `if (0 == max) { return 1; }`  All of that memory you allocated in `InverseMatrix` is now leaked if this happens.  Learn to use `std::vector` instead of resorting to `new[]/delete[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first remove initialization in you class.

```
double *pData = new double[row *row];
```

make it just this

```
double *pData;
```

Then create a proper constructor for your class, that will initialize variable `row` with `0` and `pData` with `NULL`. If you need it, create a constructor that will retrive size of your matrix like this

```
matric(int newSize) {
   // allocate memoty here
}
```